# What grass type is this - Sydney, Australia?

Tags: identification, grass

Looking to oversow some patches of my lawn and am hoping to match up to the existing grass type. We are in Sydney, Australia. Does anyone know what grass type I have?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like a Bermuda Grass Cynodon dactylon to me. Very Invasive.

[Wikipedia/Bermuda-grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynodon_dactylon)

> *From Wikipedia:*
>
> Cynodon dactylon, commonly known as Bermuda grass, is a grass found
> worldwide. It is native to Europe, Africa, Australia and much of Asia.
> It has been introduced to the Americas.[2][3] Contrary to its common
> name, it is not native to Bermuda and is in fact an abundant invasive
> species there. In Bermuda it has been known as "crab grass" (also a
> name for Digitaria sanguinalis).

[Weed Alert/ Bermuda grass](https://www.weedalert.com/weed/bermudagrass/)